# Can I turn off notifications for multiple apps at the same time?

Tags: notifications

I have many, many dozens of apps installed and hate the bother, distraction and inconvenience of notifications. I want notifications on for a very small number of apps that I'm willing to interrupt myself for. Is there a way to select multiple apps to disable notifications for all of them at the same time, ie a bulk action? It seems to take many seconds to turn off notifications for each one separately.

Comment: Please mention your device OS / version. Also mention if  your device is rooted or not

Comment: [switch off notifications](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=mrigapps.andriod.notipauser) could be tried. If device is rooted [notification off](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.aboutmycode.NotificationsOff) . Let me know